# How to set job or session priority in IIAS Database

Tags: db2, microstrategy

We want to set job priority run from Microstrategy on IIAS database at high priority but getting Syntax error for "Alter Session Set to Critical" ,

So please help if anyone knows the correct syntax for setting job or session priority to critical

Answer (score 2):

`ALTER SESSION SET TO CRITICAL` is not an IIAS command. It was available in Netezza, but IIAS now uses Db2 engine. What you need to do is to `CREATE WORKLOAD` for your  application and then associate it with the `SYSDEFAULTUSERCLASS` service class. This is more useful for monitoring purposes though, at least at this point, because you cannot create your own service classes.

If your problem are queries queuing on WLM, you might try to run:

`CALL WLM_SET_CLIENT_INFO(null,null,null,null,'SYSDEFAULTADMWORKLOAD')`

which will map current connection to administration workload which [bypasses WLM control.](https://docs-iias.mybluemix.net/docs/content/SSHRBY/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/adaptive_wlm/adaptive_wlm_query_bypass.html)

Please refer to the [Migrating workload management settings](https://docs-iias.mybluemix.net/docs/content/SSHRBY/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.apdv.porting.doc/doc/compat_wlm.html) section of the documentation for more details.

Comment: Will Set query Optimization syntax from DB2 work here on IIAS

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding that a class of jobs are not running as quickly as you might hope, then often the most profitable solution is to look to tune the SQL or DDL, rather than to tune WLM

A common opportunity on MPP systems like IIAS is to review the distribution of the tables. If tables can be distributed on join or group by columns, significant performances gains can be had.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/learn_how/choosing_dist_key_mpp.html

There are other tuning tips in this article https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogid=278&blogaid=779